# Laravel 3 - Using wpautop as a library

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I decided to use the autop function from wordpress core to automatically transform line breaks from textareas into `<p>`s and `<br>`s, and use it in my libraries folder

(By the way Laravel doesn't have any native way of doing this, right? I'd feel really stupid if it did)

---

So in `myproject/application/libraries/formatting.php` I have the following:

```
class Formatting {

    public function autop($pee, $br = true) {
       [wpautop's code here]
    }
}
```

And call it as

```
Formatting::autop($text);
```

so it returns this error

```
preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '_autop_newline_preservation_helper', to be a valid callback
```

It has to do with the following block

```
if ( $br ) {
    $pee = preg_replace_callback('/<(script|style).*?<\/\\1>/s', '_autop_newline_preservation_helper', $pee);
    $pee = preg_replace('|(?<!<br />)\s*\n|', "<br />\n", $pee); // optionally make line breaks
    $pee = str_replace('<WPPreserveNewline />', "\n", $pee);
}
```

requiring this function to be there for him

```
function _autop_newline_preservation_helper( $matches ) {
     return str_replace("\n", "<WPPreserveNewline />", $matches[0]);
}
```

This function is apparently responsible for turning single line breaks into `<br>` tags, If I remove the `if` block the code works but only with double line breaks, and I'd like to keep my `<br>`s

If I simply add this function's code in the same file as the autop function it returns the same error, I dont know the proper way to include the `_autop_newline_preservation_helper` function, what should I do?

Comment: I'ts been a while, no answers? :(

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer for myself.

I inserted the `_autop_newline_preservation_helper` function INSIDE the `autop` public function, and now it works.

I really don't know if this is a good idea so if anyone thinks this might lead to a problem, hit me up.